# Intersection of two arrays with its frequency

Tags: java

Exercise
In intersection of two arrays problem, we have given two arrays, we need to print their intersection(common elements).

```
public class IntersectionOfTwoArrays {
    private static void printIntersection(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        // Build the frequency map for arr1
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(arr1[i])) {
                map.put(arr1[i], map.get(arr1[i]) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(arr1[i], 1);
            }
        }
        // Traverse the elements of arr2 one by one
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            // If the map contains current element
            if (map.containsKey(arr2[i])) {
                // Reduce the frequency by 1
                int freq = map.get(arr2[i]);
                freq--;
                // If freq becomes 0, remove the element from the map
                if (freq == 0) {
                    map.remove(arr2[i]);
                } else {
                    map.put(arr2[i], freq);
                }
                // Print the element
                System.out.print(arr2[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I have found this implementation which looks for me really nice.
Unfortunately I do not understand deleting quantity in frequency in second part.

If map contains key from first array it should have frequency one, then if happens again it shoould go +1, why we remove element which exist in first map?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            // If the map contains current element
            if (map.containsKey(arr2[i])) {
               // Reduce the frequency by 1
                int freq = map.get(arr2[i]);
                freq--;
                // If freq becomes 0, remove the element from the map
                if (freq == 0) {
                    map.remove(arr2[i]);
                } else {
                    map.put(arr2[i], freq);
                }
```

Comment: Hint: the real answer to such problems: doing things manually first. Meaning: you **first** think up how you would solve such problems. So that you understand the options and steps, and how valid input resp. output looks like. And then, when you look at a specific solution ... you apply that knowledge. Such as: you use your input data ... and then you use a debugger (or maybe: just print statements in the code) to understand HOW that solution works. Meaning: you look at all the small steps that happen, and what they do to the data.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop counts the frequency of the elements of `arr1` in a `Map<Integer, Integer>`. The second loop considers `arr2`, where we want to find the same elements.

The important part is that we don't want to include an element of `arr2` more often than we found it in `arr1`. For example value `2` is included in `arr1` three times and in `arr2` four times.  The intersection should only be three `2`. In order to solve this problem, we decrease the frequency in the second loop.

Example for `arr1={2,2,2]` and `arr2=[2,2,2,2]` to make it clear. number before `->` is the key of the map and number after `->` is the frequency. In the first loop the frequency simply increases to three in three iterations.

Loop 1:

```
element 0: 2 -> 1
element 1: 2 -> 2
element 2: 2 -> 3
```

Loop2:

```
element 0: 2 -> 3-1; print("2")
element 1: 2 -> 2-1; print("2")
element 2: 2 -> 1-1; print("2")
element 3: 2 -> 0;
```

As you can see the loop prints three times the value `2`, which is the correct intersection. The last two is not printed as we know that in `arr1` only three `2` are included.

Answer (score 0):

Removal from the frequency map is needed to keep the matching value V<sub>i</sub> by the minimal frequency min(F1<sub>i</sub>, F2<sub>i</sub>) in both arrays.

Let's assume, `array1` is `[0, 1, 0]` and `array2` is `[1, 0, 1]`.

Then the frequency map after iterating the first array looks like `{0=2, 1=1}`, and after counting the first `1` in array2, the frequency is decreased to 0, the key `1` is removed from the map, and therefore `map.containsKey(1)` is `false` and the subsequent occurrences of `1` in array2 are excluded from the intersection.

---

Actually removal from the map may be skipped, if the remaining frequency is just compared to 0 as shown below.

Also, regarding the implementation: using method [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) may help to make the method more concise:

```java
private static void printIntersection(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    // Build the frequency map for arr1
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        map.merge(arr1[i], 1, Integer::sum); // adding occurrence in arr1
    }

    // Traverse the elements of arr2 one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        // subtracting occurrence in arr2
        if (map.merge(arr2[i], -1, Integer::sum) >= 0) {
            System.out.print(arr2[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: If I will have example arr1 [1, 2, 2] ; arr2[1, 3, 3]

When this code appears:
                int freq = map.get(arr2[i]);, then freq-- I will delete element from the map, so from my understanding won't appear in the result, so number 1 doesn't appear but it should.

Comment: In this example number 1 appears in the output as it should, because after the first array there is one occurrence: {1=1, 2=2}, then in `arr2` 1 is detected, `freq--` -> `freq = 0`, and the entry is deleted from the map `{2=2}`.  After that `arr2` does not contain `1`, but even if it did, the map does not have key `1` any longer.